# Canvas- house. Why isn`t the code working, when I copy it to an editor and run it in my browser?

Tags: javascript, html

```
http://codepen.io/kratka/pen/YywpXV
```

What do I have to do, to make it work? I copy the code, and I am pretty sure I am missing something vital. Or is it something I have to remove from the code? Maybe I should just learn more about canvas, and build it from the ground up. But it seems more convenient to use the example, at least as a blueprint.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
     <title>Test</title>
   </head>
  <body>

<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>  

<script="text/javascript">

var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var c = canvas.getContext('2d');
c.canvas.width  = window.innerWidth;
c.canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
var cX = canvas.width / 2;
var cY = canvas.height / 2;
var blue = "#447FFF";
var white = "#FFF";

// house body
c.beginPath();
c.rect(cX - 100, cY - 50, 200, 200);
c.fillStyle = blue;
c.fill();
c.closePath();

// window
c.beginPath();
c.rect(cX - 70, cY - 20, 40, 40);
c.fillStyle = white;
c.fill();
c.closePath();

// roof
c.beginPath();
c.moveTo(cX - 100, cY - 50);
c.lineTo(cX, cY - 150);
c.lineTo(cX + 100, cY - 50);
c.lineTo(cX - 100, cY -50);
c.fillStyle = blue;
c.fill();
c.closePath();

// door
c.beginPath();
c.rect(cX + 20, cY + 71, 50, 80);
c.fillStyle = white;
c.fill();
c.closePath();

// roof decor
for (var j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
   c.beginPath();
   c.moveTo((cX - 70) + (i * 20), (cY - 50) - (j * 20));
   c.lineTo((cX - 80) + (i * 20), (cY - 60) - (j * 20));
   c.moveTo((cX - 110) + (i * 20), (cY - 50) - (j * 20));
   c.lineTo((cX - 90) + (i * 20), (cY - 70) - (j * 20));
   c.strokeStyle = white;
   c.stroke();
   c.closePath();
  }
}

// body decor
for (var j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
  for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
   c.beginPath();
   c.moveTo((cX - 100) + (i * 30), (cY + 135) - (j * 30));
   c.lineTo((cX - 130) + (i * 30), (cY + 135) - (j * 30));
   c.lineTo((cX - 130) + (i * 30), (cY + 150) - (j * 30));
   if ( j != 6 ) {
   c.moveTo((cX - 115) + (i * 30), (cY + 135) - (j * 30));
   c.lineTo((cX - 115) + (i * 30), (cY + 120) - (j * 30));
   c.lineTo((cX - 85) + (i * 30), (cY + 120) - (j * 30));
   }
   //c.rect((cX - 100) + (i * 30), (cY + 135) - (j * 30), 30, 15);
   //if ( j != 6 ) {
     //c.rect((cX - 85) + (i * 30), (cY + 120) - (j * 30), 30, 15);
   //}
   c.strokeStyle = white;
   c.stroke();
   c.closePath();
  }
}

// chimney
c.beginPath();
c.rect(cX + 60, cY - 120, 20, 50);
c.rect(cX + 50, cY - 130, 40, 10);
c.fillStyle = blue;
c.fill();
c.closePath();

// window lines
c.beginPath();
c.moveTo(cX - 70, cY);
c.lineTo(cX - 30, cY);
c.moveTo(cX - 50, cY - 20);
c.lineTo(cX - 50, cY + 20);
c.strokeStyle = blue;
c.lineWidth = 2;
c.stroke();
c.closePath();


</script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Include the `canvas` element (with an id of `canvas`) between the body tags?

Comment: Have done it, still not working @evolutionxbox.

Comment: "Still not working" is not helpful. Please describe the issue. Have you got any console errors? Also, remove `="text/javascript"`.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/q5kwv5s1/

Comment: Not any console errors.

Comment: You changed the issue now. The question as it stands is about the canvas not appearing, your fiddle shows that to be fixed.

Comment: Yes, so what is the issue now? Sorry for not mentioning that.

Comment: Not sure. I recommend creating a new question based on what you expect to see, and what you're getting.

Comment: Yes, was about to do that. But not sure if it was "worthy" another question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good job, but your issue is with how you defined your script:

`<script="text/javascript">...`

should be

`<script type="text/javascript">...`

and most people just use

`<script>...`